# Need to add child record in case related list if same record is present in sfdc

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, case

Requirement is :-When record is getting created in sfdc in case object,It needs to check the Contact Email of case and if the record is already present with this email then new recods needs to be added as a child record in case . I  dont understand how to go ahead.Is process builder can do it?
[image]

If suppose new record is created with OrderNumber or Contact email with same in screenshot then needs to be added in related list of case

Comment: what is the child record? Is that custom object's record?

Comment: No its CASE record itself and need to add in related cases

Comment: so, basically if contact email exists for other cases then those cases will be added as related cases under this case?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Not able to figure out if any out of box option

Comment: Hi Anybody knows how we can do this by using OOB like Proces builder to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in trigger (after insert), refer the in-line comment to understand the logic

```
trigger myCaseTrigger on Case (after insert)
{
    Map<Id, String> mapCase = new Map<Id, String>();
    //collect all the cases where ContactEmail exists
    for(Case caseObj:Trigger.new)
    {
        if(caseObj.ContactEmail != null)
        {
            mapCase.put(caseObj.Id,caseObj.ContactEmail);
        }
    }

    //based on the ContactEmail retrieve other cases.
    List<Case> lstCase = [SELECT Id,ContactEmail, ParentId 
                            FROM Case 
                            WHERE ContactEmail IN:mapCase.values() 
                            AND Id NOT IN:mapCase.keySet()];

    //now compare the contactEmail and assign the ParentId.
    for(Case caseObj:Trigger.new)
    {
        if(caseObj.ContactEmail != null)
        {
            for(Case cs:lstCase)
            {
                if(caseObj.ContactEmail == cs.ContactEmail)
                {
                    cs.ParentId = caseObj.Id;               
                }           
            }   
        }       
    }
    update lstCase;
}
```

*Note: I didn't compiled the code, but logic will be as above. It should work.*

Comment: is there any conbfiguration solution which can be used?

Comment: you can use flows. otherwise suggest you to go through some trailheads to understand what can be achievable by process builder, workflow, flows and apex

Comment: take the updated code and run at your DE

Comment: Thanks for solution ,but here happening somthing different.

Comment: If I have CASE 1  with abc@gmail.com in salesforce and i am Going to cereate CASE 2 with same email,then my CASE1 should be parent and CASE2 needs to be related but above code doing opposite .

Comment: you should write your logic and if you face any issues then post it